# Unable to insert data into mysql database using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a timeline like project which allows to write comments on the posts. But I'm unable to insert the data. Comments are getting displayed as expected. The form values does not seem to pass on to the save_comments.php page.

Below's the codes

**config.php**

```
<?php

   $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=posts&comments","root","");
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    include 'config.php';
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>




<?php


$sql=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
$sql->execute();
$results=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "<hr>";
foreach($results as $post){
    echo "<h2>".$post['post_title']."</h2><br>";
    echo $post['post_content']."<br>";
    ?>
<br><b>Comments</b>
<form id=comment_form_<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?> action="">
    <input type=hidden name=pid value=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?> >
    <p><input type=text name=cbody id="comment_body_<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>" placeholder="Write comment" ></p>
    <p><input type=text name= cauth id="comment_author_<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>" placeholder="Your Name" ></p>
    <p><button class="submit_comment" post_id="<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>" >Submit</button> </p>

</form>
<p><button class="show_comments" post_id="<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>">Show comments</button></p>
<div id="comments_<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>">


</div>
    <?php
   echo "<hr>"; 
}
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".show_comments").click(function() {
            var post_id=$(this).attr('post_id'); 
            $("#comments_"+post_id).load("comments.php", {
                post_id:post_id
            }); 
    });
        $(".submit_comment").on("click",function() {
            var post_id=$(this).attr('post_id');
            $.ajax({
                data:$('#comment_form_'+post_id).serialize(),
                url:'save_comments.php',
                async : true,
                success: function(){
                    $("#comments_"+post_id).load("comments.php", {
                        post_id:post_id
                     }); 
                }
            })
        });
    });

</script>
```

**comments.php**

```
<?php

include 'config.php';
$post_id=$_POST['post_id'];
$pid=$post_id;
$sql1=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments where post_id=:pid");
$sql1->bindParam(':pid',$pid);
$sql1->execute();
$results1=$sql1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($results1 as $comment){
echo "<br><b><cite>".$comment['comment_author']."</cite></b><br>";
echo $comment['comment_body']."<br>";
}
```

?>

**save_comments.php**

```
    <?php

include 'config.php';

$comment_body=$_POST['cbody'];
$comment_author=$_POST['cauth'];
$post_id=$_POST['pid'];   
$sql2=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO comments Values(NULL,:pid,:cauth,:cbody)");
$sql2->bindParam(':pid',$post_id);
$sql2->bindParam(':cauth',$comment_author);
$sql2->bindParam(':cbody',$comment_body);
$sql2->execute();
?>
```

PS: I'm still a beginner at AJAX & jquery

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: What debugging have you done?

Comment: `$.ajax` uses `GET` by default.

Comment: Also since you aren't adding the columns in the query,  verify that the values match

Comment: I thought it used POST. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not defining the ajax request as a `POST`and therefor no POST variables are sent.

```
$.ajax({
  data:$('#comment_form_'+post_id).serialize(),
  url:'save_comments.php',
  async : true,
  method: 'POST', <---- ADD THIS
  success: function(){
      $("#comments_"+post_id).load("comments.php", {
          post_id:post_id
       }); 
  }
})
```